# Laravel Page Refresh

Tags: php, command-line, laravel, laravel-4

I'm working within Laravel, when I serve a development server through the command line `php artisan serve`, and save my changes on text editor, I get the desired results. However if I make a change in the editor and refresh nothing changes within the browser, until a few minutes later.

Also as a side question, when I run `php artisan serve` I can no longer continue typing and entering commands.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me that you're having some kind of trouble with something else, not Laravel, nor PHP web server.

PHP builtin web server was made to serve pages dinamically and Laravel doesn't cache much of your code, just some views, but if the view changes it recompiles it. Everything else is dynamic, you make a change it shows to you in the next refresh.

Do a very basic test, create a new route and use it to test:

```
Route::get('test', function() {

    dd( 'this is a test and value is 1' );

});
```

Point your browser to http:///test and you must see the phrase. Change it and hit F5, it must change.

About your prompt needs, you have 2 options:

-Open a new terminal just to run `php artisan serve`

-Run it on background, wich also has, at least, 2 options:

1. Hit CTRL+Z on terminal (it will say "Stopped") and then execute `bg` and it will show `php artisan serve &`
2. This is exactly your second option, you can just run it by doing:

   **php artisan serve &**

In both cases you'll have your prompt back.

Comment: Or run `php artisan serve` in a separate tab

Answer (score 0):

If the condition is true this line of code will make you stay in the current page and display message "You must be logged in"

```
if(!(session()->has('Loggedin')) && (($request->path() !='auth.login')))
{
            return back()->with('fail', 'You must be logged in');
}
```